# Gazebo not running correctly after installation on ubuntu 14.04 on VM

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, I have having trouble with running gazebo. I was originally hitting an error regarding name spaces but i found a fix which involved downloading the gazebo models and putting them in the gazebo directory. Now however I have a new error appearing when i try to run gazebo. This is running on ubuntu 14.04 on a virtual machine. The main error seems to be to do with inconsistent values but I may be wrong. I know this can work correctly on the virtual machine with ubuntu 14.04 as a fellow student has it running correctly, we just cant work out whats wrong with mine as he never had this problem.

I think it has something to do with this line:
Warning [parser_urdf.cc:1010] multiple inconsistent <self_collide> exists due to fixed joint reduction overwriting previous value [true] with [false].

Below is the output im receiving:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/a878aff8f5ff7642d6a414632cb7b949

Please any help would be very appreciated as i really need to get this working.

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275391/gazebo-not-running-correctly-after-installation-on-ubuntu-14.04-on-vm/) by [marshy933](https://answers.ros.org/users/32546/marshy933/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-11-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have controller_manager installed? It seems like not, try running:

`sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-controller-manager`

I am assuming that you have ROS indigo installed, if you have kinetic then use:

`sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-controller-manager`

**EDIT:** I think I found your issue, didn't saw that you were using VMware, while VMs tend to have issues with Gazbo, it depends on you local hardware, how much ram are you assigning to that VM? What is your graphics card?
This answer in the gazebo forums seems to give some guidelines:
http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13214/virtual-machine-not-launching-gazebo/
It is some graphics acceleration with your VM, try unchecking "Accelerate 3D Graphics" in your VMware settings.

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marshy933](https://answers.ros.org/users/32546/marshy933/) on 2017-11-08**:
Hi there, yes i have the controller_manager installed

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2017-11-08**:
Might also try looking if the gazebo plugin is in the robot model, it should look something like this:

```
<gazebo>
  <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
    <robotNamespace>/MYROBOT</robotNamespace>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2017-11-08**:
This is a relevant answer:
https://answers.ros.org/question/214712/gazebo-controller-spawner-warning/

**Comment by [marshy933](https://answers.ros.org/users/32546/marshy933/) on 2017-11-08**:
Hi there so the accelerate definitely helped when i unchecked it, its not crashing now. although still having the problems with it saying it
[WARN] [WallTime: 1510175651.323128] [1.318000] Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.

**Comment by [marshy933](https://answers.ros.org/users/32546/marshy933/) on 2017-11-08**:
that point you made about the gazebo plugin, how do i check it? I checked that other answer you linked but cant see how to check the plugin is correctly being accessed

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2017-11-09**:
Check the urdf file of the baxter robot, it should be there though, btw, mind the upvote? ;)